# scope of regexp-match related pseudo variables

Tags: ruby, regex, scope

In the following:

```
def foo
   p $`, $&, $'
end
def bar x = $`, y = $&, z = $'
   p x, y, z
end

'abc' =~ /b/

p $`, $&, $' # => 'a', 'b', 'c'
foo # => nil, nil, nil
bar # => nil, nil, nil
```

the pseudo variables related to regexp match seem to be reset within foo, and even within the argument receiving part in bar. I know that this has something to do with scope, but my understanding is that, a variable preceding and outside of a scope can be normally seen from inside that scope (besides some environments related to eval, exec, and the like) even though a variable inside a scope cannot be seen from the outside.

Can you tell me the nature of the scope of these regexp related pseudo variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexp related pseudo variables don't act like global variables, but are local to the method and thread you're using them in.

I think this is mentioned in "Programming Ruby" - do you have a copy?

To fix your problem: try only passing the values in `$backtick` and `$&` to `foo` and `bar`, and if they have an exception, let them raise an exception, and have the calling method handle the exception, log what's in `$'`, and then re-raise the exception:

```
def foo(x, y)
  raise if x != "hello"
end

def caller_of_foo
  begin
    foo($`, $&) # Ignore this comment: `
  rescue
    STDERR.puts "foo raised #{$!.inspect}"
    STDERR.puts "The remainder of the regexp is #{$'.inspect}"
    raise
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to access the last match information within a method definition without having it passed as an argument, as in foo or bar above?

Comment: @sawa: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am using a gsub loop against a huge text to parse a DSL, and for each run within the loop, want to keep track of the match position, so that it can return the position information in case an error occurs. I have a class that takes care of the errors, so for each run within the gsub loop, the match position is recorded. However, passing $` (which can become huge) each time as an argument to a method seems to take enourmous amount of time. Even assingning a variable like x = $` many times seems to extremely slow down.

Comment: So I wanted to have a method that can refer to last match without having it passed aa an argument.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think that is the path that I should take. I will handle the information regarding the error position within the caller method.